# Embedding a disc in a simply connected surface

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology

> Let $\Sigma$ be a simply connected surface possibly non-compact with
> boundary. Is it true that any simple closed curve in $\Sigma$ bounds a
> disc?

When $\Sigma=\Bbb R^2,\Bbb S^2$ this is certainly true by the Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem. Any reference or proof will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** If $\Sigma$ is a simply-connected non-compact surface with boundary and the simple closed curve is contained in $\text{Int}(\Sigma)$, then $\text{Int}(\Sigma)$ is homotopically equivalent to $\Sigma$ by collar-neighborhood theorem, and so $\text{Int}(\Sigma)$ is simply connected. Also, $\text{Int}(\Sigma)$ is non-compact, hence $\text{Int}(\Sigma)=\Bbb R^2$ by Uniformazation theorem. So, we are done Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: Could you elaborate why this is not immediate from the definition of "simply connected"?

Comment: The embedded simple closed curve could be too weird, and that is why we consider the plane Jordan Curve theorem though **intuitively** plane Jordan curve theorem is very clear for some nice enough embedded simple closed curve.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: For instance because a similar statement fails in dimension 3: $R^3$ contains nontrivial knots and wild spheres.

Comment: This follows from Schoenflies theorem.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry, but how do I embed the whole simple closed curve in a single open connected subset $U$ of $\Sigma$ such that there is a homeomorphism from $U$ onto an open subset of $\{z\in\Bbb C:\text{Im}(z)\geq 0\}$?

Comment: Seems like I need to use $\Sigma$ is simply connected.